# Merge sort in java. Sometimes sorts sometimes goes into an Infinite Loop

Tags: java, sorting, loops, merge, infinite

I'm writing a merge sort in java.
It sometimes sorts the array and sometimes goes into an infinitive loop.I can't find why.
Thank you for help.

```
// M - Main Array
                int Aindex = 0;
                int Bindex = 0;
                int A[] = new int[(int) (M.length + 1) / 2];
                int B[] = new int[(int) M.length / 2];
                while (!sakartotsAugosi(M)) { // While not sorted Look below for this function.
                    Aindex = 0;
                    Bindex = 0;
                    for (int Mindex = 0; Mindex < M.length; Mindex++) {
                        if ((Mindex + 1) % 2 != 0) {
                            A[Aindex] = M[Mindex];
                            Aindex++;
                        } else {
                            B[Bindex] = M[Mindex];
                            Bindex++;
                        }
                    }


                    Aindex = 0;
                    Bindex = 0;
                    for (int Mindex = 0; Mindex < M.length; Mindex++) {
                        if (Aindex == A.length) {
                            M[Mindex] = B[Bindex];
                            Bindex++;
                        } else if (Bindex == B.length) {
                            M[Mindex] = A[Aindex];
                            Aindex++;
                        } else if (A[Aindex] <= B[Bindex]) {
                            M[Mindex] = A[Aindex];
                            Aindex++;
                        } else if (B[Bindex] <= A[Aindex]) {
                            M[Mindex] = B[Bindex];
                            Bindex++;
                        }
                    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public boolean sakartotsAugosi(int M[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < M.length; i++) {
        if (M[i - 1] > M[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this is not how a merge sort works. I'd advise you read the wiki article or something first and redo your implementation.

Comment: Uhm, maybe I don't know the correct name for it? Is it a different sorting algorithm?

Comment: no, it looks like you are trying to make a merge sort here, but your approach is incorrect. You are supposed to split the array in to two parts, mergesort each part, then merge them. You are doing the first step and the last step, but not the middle one. See the wiki page for more info.

Comment: But the thing is this is how my teacher showed me this. And the thing is that it actually sorts sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't sort. But Ill check the wiki. :)

Comment: it only sorts sometimes if you are lucky. Consider this list: `0 1 4 2 7 9 3 8`. After one iteration of your while loop, what does it look like?

Comment: It looks like 0 1 2 4 7 3 9 8. Next it looks like 0 1 2 4 3 7 8 9.  And next it looks like 0 1 2 3 4 7 8 9.

Comment: you aren't going to be able to fix your code if you don't know how it works in the first place. `M = [0 1 4 2 7 9 3 8]`, `A = [0 1 4 2]`, `B = [7 9 3 8]`. You think that the first run of your for loop will result in  `M = [0 1 2 4 7 3 9 8]` (`A = [0 1 2 4]`). How can your for loop swap values within `A[]` if it is iterating sequentially? Here's what will happen: `B[0]` is greater than everything in `A[]`, so `A[Aindex] <= B[Bindex]` is always true, which means your start with `M = [0 1 2 4]`. Then `Aindex == A.length` is always true, so you end with `M = [0 1 4 2 7 9 3 8]`.

Comment: @Red Alert :Nop, that is not how it works. M = [0 1 4 2 7 9 3 8], A[0 4 7 3],B[1 2 9 8]. It divides it like that. Look at the code at first for loop. It works like this i == 1 Copy M[0] to A[0]. i++; i == 2 Copy M[1] to B[0] i++;